# Natural map from spectrum of local ring (Lemma II 4.4 Hartshorne)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $R$ be a valuation ring of a field $K$. Let $T=\operatorname{Spec} R$ and let $U=\operatorname{Spec}K$.In Harthorne Lemma II.4.4 he proves that given a scheme $X$, a morphism of $T$ to $X$ is equivalent to giving two points $x_0,x_1$ in $X$, with $x_0 \in \overline{\{x_1\}}$ and an inclusion $k(x_1)\subseteq K$, such that $R$ dominates the local ring $\mathcal{O}$ of $x_0$ on the subscheme $Z= \overline{\{x_1\}}$ of $X$ with its reduced induced structure.

Q1: The morphism $T \to X$ factors though $Z$: $T \to Z \to X$, and the first component of this induces two maps:
$$
O_{Z, x_0} \to O_{T, t_0} = R
$$
$$
O_{Z, x_1} \to O_{T, t_1} = K.
$$

From here it should follow that $O_{Z, x_0}$ dominates $R$:
that the first map is in fact an inclusion and that the 
$O_{Z, x_0} \cap m_{R} = m_{x_0}$, where $m_{x_0}$ is the unique maximal ideal of $O_{Z, x_0}$, and $m_R$ that of $R$.

Q2: In the converse direction, he states that the map $T \to X$ is obtained by  composing $\operatorname{Spec} \ R \to \operatorname{Spec} \ O_{Z, x_0} $, induced by $O_{Z, x_0} \to R$, 
with the natural map $\operatorname{Spec} \ O_{Z, x_0} \to X$. How is this natural map defined? Thank you.

Comment: There's a natural map $\operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0}\to Z$ which is given by sending the unique point of the local ring to $x_0$ and the sheaf morphism can be defined on an open set $U$ by taking the natural map from any open containing $x_0$ to the stalk at $x_0$. Compose this with the closed immersion $Z\to X$ to get your desired map.

Comment: Two more things: please use \operatorname{Spec} to write out $\operatorname{Spec}$ instead of the TeX hack you were using before, and please try to make your question titles more descriptive - you had two questions which were nearly identically titled about different aspects of the same problem.

Comment: @KReiser Yes, will do from now on. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnnyT. Hi this might be late but may I ask why is the first arrow $O_{Z,z_0}\rightarrow O_{T,t_0} = R$ injective?

Answer (score 1):

For the second question, $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0}$ can be considered as a local ring of some affine subscheme of $Z$, say $\operatorname{Spec}A$. Then its clear that $\mathcal{O}_{Z,x_0}=A_\mathfrak{p}$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ is the prime ideal corresponding to the point $x_0$. Since the open immersion $\operatorname{Spec}A\rightarrow Z$ has been defined, it suffices to give a homomorphism from $A$ to $A_\mathfrak{p}$, which is natural.